how to start the mongodb server?
{"t":{"$date":"2024-10-14T15:12:46.202+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-10-14T15:12:49.821+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
what type of error is this? how to resolve this ?
i want to start mangodb server

These are not errors - the severity is informational.  See Log Messages for more on how to interpret Mongo log messages.
In short, you have two log entries that are presented in JSON format.  The first one is telling you that TLS 1.0 has been automatically disabled.  Nothing wrong with that.
{ "t":{"$date":"2024-10-14T15:12:46.202+05:30"}
, "s":"I"
, "c":"CONTROL"
, "id":23285
, "ctx":"thread1"
, "msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"} 

This second entry is telling you that multi-threading is initialized.  Nothing wrong with that either.
{ "t":{"$date":"2024-10-14T15:12:49.821+05:30"}
, "s":"I"
, "c":"CONTROL"
, "id":5945603
, "ctx":"thread1"
, "msg":"Multi threading initialized"}

There is nothing here that indicates that you have failed to start MongoDB.
